IMPORTXML script not working: Outputs formula not the result
I'm trying to use IMPORTXML in a custom function by passing a ticker symbol so I can avoid retyping a long formula each time, when only the ticker symbol is changing.
Unfortunately my script displays the formula in the cell rather than the result of the formula.
If I copy and paste the displayed formula into another cell, and then adding and remove a character, that cell will then display the result of the formula instead of the formula itself. It's as if I need to activate it the formula.
Custom Function
function fveps2(ticker) {
  var url = `https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=${ticker}`;
  var Xpath_1 = '/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]';
  var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + url + '","'+ Xpath_1 + '")';
  return importXpath_1;
}

The formula that is returned that doesn't work without pasting and activating:
=IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=","/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")


You are apparently trying to implement fveps2() as a custom function. That will not work, because custom functions cannot set values — they can only return values. You cannot set a formula this way.
The easiest way to do this is to use a normal importxml() formula that stays the same. Make that formula refer to a cell that is changed periodically using a script that runs on a time-driven trigger.
See What are the refresh characteristics of the Google Spreadsheet Import functions? for sample code.

I'm not sure i understand your answer, I want the result of the function, I don't want to set a value, I would like to have the function work so it can return the value to the specified ticker but by creating a function makes it easier to call or get the value so rather than write importxml(....etc y can use my function and change the xpath to get the desired value from the source url, I hope I'm being clear, thanks!

The =importxml(...) thing is a formula. To get the result of the formula, you would have to use .setFormula() to put the formula in a cell. You cannot do that from a custom function such as your fveps2() function. To solve this in a different way, use the recipe I gave you and see the page I linked.

As @doubleunary noted in their answer, you need to set a cell value but you cannot using the custom function.
To achieve your objective you could use either:

An onEdit(e) simple trigger and simulate a custom function, or
Create a named function in Sheets

1.  Simulated custom function using onEdit(e)

The constant name stores the name of the simulated custom function  fveps

Each time a cell is edited, the script uses a regular expression to check if the edited cell value is either fveps(ticker) or fveps("ticker") where ticker can be any character(s). For simplicity you can include either or both of the quotation marks or exclude them.

If matched, the script sets your formula in the edited cell, otherwise it does nothing.
Script
// Simulated custom function to overcome some
// security limitations of custom functions

// Enter in Sheets as text NOT formula:
// GOOD: 'myFunction(param)' or 'myFunction("param")'
// BAD:  '=myFunction(param)' or '=myFunction("param")'

// Set functionName, url, xpath, as desired 
const functionName = 'fveps'; 
const url = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' 
const xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/strong';

function onEdit(e) {
  const re = new RegExp(`^${functionName}\\("?(.*?)"?\\)$`);
  const groups = e.value.match(re);
  if (groups) {
    e.range.setFormula('=IMPORTXML("' + url + groups[1] + '", "'+ xpath + '")');
  }
}




2.  Named function in Sheets

Navigate to Data > Named functions

Name your function FVEPS, for example,and optionally provide a description.

Create an Argument placeholder for your ticker symbol ticker

Enter your formula definition which is equivalent to your formula with your ticker placeholder representing where the user input goes. For example:
=IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&ticker,
 "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/strong")


Use your named function making sure your user input is quoted. For example:
=FVEPS("WINT")






